# Notifications not firing on boot

Tags: java, android, android-intent, intentfilter, boot

I'm trying to fire a notification after a boot/reboot. However, despite adding what I thought was necessary in the android manifest and checking for the right action the notification still doesn't fire.

**Note:**  *fireNotification(context)* is fully functional. In other words: it fires a notification if I remove the test methods.

**Inside my subclass of BroadcastReceiver:**

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction()) ||
            "android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        fireNotification(context);
    }
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <receiver android:name="com.example.morgonnotification.ReminderReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity android:name="com.example.morgonnotification.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Did you launch `MainActivity` at least once after installation, before rebooting?

Comment: @MikeM. Yes! However, the MainActivity solely creates the notification channels.

Comment: @MikeM. I realised I needed to move the channel creation to the onReceive method, so the channel exists after reboot. Now it works! Thank you very much. I wish I could accept your comment as an answer.

Comment: Hmm, you shouldn't have to recreate the `NotificationChannel`s each time, so I'm not sure what you did to get it working. Glad you did, though. Cheers!

Comment: @MikeM. You're right, actually. It is working either way, so then it's not clear to me why I don't have to re-create the channel. I thought MainActivity, and therefore the onCreate (which creates the channel), doesn't run after reboot. I suppose I was wrong.